# Configuring cloudwatch alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

Question I want to create alarm so that if the status check failed for 5 times or more in 10 minutes, then raise alarm.  Basically, I want to check if the instance is alive or not , for which I plan to use systemCheckFailed metrics.
I am not so sure if I am using the right values as below .

mon-put-metric-alarm TestAlarm  --comparisonoperator  GreaterThanThreshold  --evaluation-periods  5 --metric-name  StatusCheckFailed  --namespace  "AWS/EC2"  --period  600  --statistic Average --threshold  5 --alarm-actions arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:764516644405:scalingPolicy:dtestguid:autoScalingGroupName/WebAutoScaleGroup:policyName/WebScaleUp --dimensions "AutoScalingGroupName=WebAutoScaleGroup"

Answer (score 2):

I think the command you specified will fire the alarm after 5 (evaluation-periods) times with an interval of 600 seconds (period)...i.e. not what you want.  If you want to check the value 5 times in 10 minutes you need to say evaluation-periods:5, -period:120.